# How do I prove the circumference of an ellipse

Tags: arc-length

I'm trying to find the circumference of an ellipse with a horizontal radius of $h$ and a vertical radius of $k$. The equation for such an ellipse centered at the origin would by $(x/h)^2 + (y/k)^2 = 1$. I've tried the arc-length formula in both cartesian form and parametric form, and got stuck on both of them.

First, I set $f(x) = \dfrac{k}{h}\sqrt{(h^2 - x^2)}$. I tried to solve $2\displaystyle\int_{-h}^h \sqrt{f'(x))^2 + 1} \:dx$, and managed to get it down to the following:

$\displaystyle\dfrac{2k}{h}\int_{-h}^h\sqrt{\dfrac{x^2}{(h^2 - x^2) + (h/k)^2}}dx$

But I didn't know how to go from there either.

Next, I set $f(t) = h\cos(t)$ and $g(t) = k\sin(t)$. I tried to solve $\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}(f'(t))^2 + (g'(t))^2 dx$, and managed to get it down to the following.

$\displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sqrt{h\sin^2(t) + k\cos^2(t)}dt$

Once again, I didn't know how to go on.

Comment: see answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1964731/59379).

Answer (score 1):

The perimeter of an ellipse cannot be in general calculated analytically, you can solve it numerically. Here you can see the wikipedia article for [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). What you are concretly looking for is the [complete elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) forms.

I said in general because we know analytically the perimeter of a circunference, which is a particular case of an ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the answer in the form of an infinite series. For an ellipse $E$ with semi major axis of length $a$ and semi minor axis of length $b$ with $a>b>0$, then we have the circumference $C$ having the formula
$$C=2\pi a\left[ 1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty }{{{\left( \prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}} \right)}^{2}}\frac{{{e}^{2i}}}{2i-1}} \right],$$ where $e=\sqrt{1-\frac{{{b}^{2}}}{{{a}^{2}}}}$ denotes the eccentricity of $E$.

**Proof**

We first parametrise the ellipse. That is $x=a\cos\theta$ and $y=b\sin\theta$. Then, by considering the eccentricity, we have ${{b}^{2}}={{a}^{2}}\left( 1-{{e}^{2}} \right)$.

Now, we compute $C$.

$$\begin{align}
  & \int_{0}^{2\pi }{\sqrt{{{\left( \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}\theta } \right)}^{2}}+{{\left( \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}\theta } \right)}^{2}}}\text{ d}\theta }=\int_{0}^{2\pi }{\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\theta +{{b}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta }\text{ d}\theta } \\ 
 & =4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\theta +{{b}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta }\text{ d}\theta } \\ 
 & =4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\theta +{{a}^{2}}\left( 1-{{e}^{2}} \right){{\cos }^{2}}\theta }\text{ d}\theta } \\ 
 & =4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{{{a}^{2}}-{{a}^{2}}{{e}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta }\text{ d}\theta } \\ 
 & =4a\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{1-{{e}^{2}}{{\cos }^{2}}\theta }\text{ d}\theta } \\ 
 & =4a\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{1-{{e}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\left( \theta +\frac{\pi }{2} \right)}\text{ d}\theta } \\ 
 & =4a\int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\pi }{\sqrt{1-{{e}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}t}\text{ d}t} \\ 
 & =4a\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{1-{{e}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\theta }\text{ d}\theta }
\end{align}$$

By the Reduction Formula which involves integration by parts, one can show that$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{{{\sin }^{2i}}\theta \text{ d}\theta }=\frac{\pi }{2}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}}.$$

Using the Binomial Theorem and Fubini's Theorem,
$$\begin{align}
  & 4a\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sqrt{1-{{e}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\theta }\text{ d}\theta }=4a\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\left( \begin{matrix}
  {}^{1}/{}_{2} \\ 
  i \\ 
\end{matrix} \right)}{{\left( -{{e}^{2}}{{\sin }^{2}}\theta  \right)}^{i}}\text{ d}\theta } \\ 
 & =4a\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\left( {{e}^{2i}}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{{}^{3}/{}_{2}-j}{j}}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}{{{\sin }^{2i}}\theta \text{ d}\theta } \right)} \\ 
 & =2\pi a\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\left( {{e}^{2i}}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{{}^{3}/{}_{2}-j}{j}}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}} \right)} \\ 
 & =2\pi a\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\left( {{e}^{2i}}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{3-2j}{2j}}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}} \right)} \\ 
 & =2\pi a\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\left( {{e}^{2i}}{{\left( -1 \right)}^{i}}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-3}{2j}}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}} \right)} \\ 
 & =2\pi a\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\left[ {{\left( \prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}} \right)}^{2}}\frac{{{e}^{2i}}{{\left( -1 \right)}^{i}}}{1-2i} \right]} \\ 
 & =2\pi a\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty }{\left[ {{\left( \prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}} \right)}^{2}}\frac{{{e}^{2i}}{{\left( -1 \right)}^{i}}}{1-2i} \right]} \\ 
 & =2\pi a\left[ 1-\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty }{{{\left( \prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}} \right)}^{2}}\frac{{{e}^{2i}}}{2i-1}} \right].  
\end{align}$$

**Remark:** $$\prod\limits_{j=1}^{i}{\frac{2j-1}{2j}}=\frac{\left( 2i \right)!}{{{2}^{2i}}{{\left( i! \right)}^{2}}}$$